# How to add a translatable string to post date

Tags: translation

I am trying to add a translatable string, like "posted on:" to my Wordpress theme post dates. I have already added a font-awesome icon next to it and I'd like to have the string after the icon. The code for the date is

```
$time = '<i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>' . '<time datetime=' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '>' . get_the_time('j F Y') . '</time>'
```

I know that, to make a string translatable in Wordpress, I need to add the string inside `__()`, but can I do so for the above code?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [placeholders](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Placeholders):

```
$time = sprintf( 
    '<i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> %s: 
     <time datetime="%s">%s</time>', 
     esc_html__('Posted on', 'textdomain'), 
     get_the_time('Y-m-d'), 
     get_the_time('j F Y') 
);
```